# Linq to SQL File Size

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

What I want to learn is if we put every table into one LinqToSQL file, do we lose performance? Is it better to put each table in different LinqToSQL Files or it's the same thing with putting in single one.

I hope I have explained my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There won't be a run-time penalty, but it may slow intelisense down once you get to millions of tables in a single file.

For what it's worth, the default SQL Metal behaviour puts all tables in a database into a single file.